# How do I focus a TextInput custom component using hooks?

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to get a TextInput to gain focus on a button click but the TextInput is inside a custom component. I can get it to work if the TextInput is not inside a custom component and I found a couple answer for inside a custom component but not when using hooks.

When I try this way, I get the error: `Uncaught TypeError: usernameTextInput.current is null`.

Screen A:

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import { Pressable, Text } from "react-native";
import MyTextInput from "../components/MyTextInput";

const ScreenA = () => {
  const refTextInput = useRef(null);

  return (
    <MyTextInput
      ref={refTextInput}
      ...
    />
    <Pressable onPress={() => refTextInput.current.focus()}>
      <Text>Focus</Text>
    </Pressable>
  );
};

export default ScreenA;
```

MyTextInput Component:

```
import { TextInput } from "react-native";

const MyTextInput = (props) => {
  return (
    <TextInput
      ref={props.ref}
      ...
    />
  );
};

export default MyTextInput;
```

If I replace `<MyInputText/>` with `<InputText/>` then it focuses. How to I properly pass the focus request to my custom component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that you have to use "forwarding ref" concept:

try below code:

Screen A:

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import { Pressable, SafeAreaView, Text, View } from "react-native";
import MyTextInput from "./components/MyTextInput";

const App = () => {
  const refTextInput = React.createRef(null);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <MyTextInput ref={refTextInput} />
      <Pressable onPress={() => refTextInput.current.focus()}>
        <Text>Focus</Text>
      </Pressable>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default App;
```

MyTextInput Component:

```
import { TextInput } from "react-native";
import React from "react";
const MyTextInput = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return <TextInput ref={ref} />;
});

export default MyTextInput;
```

For "forwarding ref" concept you can refer to this doc:
https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html